# How to return 1 row when searching for a key in multiple tables and returning a concatenated result in a column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Context:

- I have a list of `stores` where I need to use the store's name to match against any combination of the `franchise`, `north_region` or `south_region` as they are named differently depending on the region or whether you're a store or franchise. I need to match the names so we can find the right `franchise`
- I need the correct Franchise to find the opening `franchise_location` information

`stores` table

| id | name | franchise_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mc Donalds | 1 |
| 2 | KFC | 2 |
| 3 | Burgers & Kings | 3 |
| 4 | Dominos | 4 |
| 5 | Pizzzzzzzzzza Hutter | 5 |

`franchises` table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mc Donalds |
| 2 | Kentucky |
| 3 | Burger King |
| 4 | Dominos Pizza |
| 5 | Pizza Hut |

`northern_region` table

| id | name | franchise_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | KFC | 2 |
| 2 | Burgers & Kings | 3 |
| 3 | Pizzzzzzzzzza Hutter | 5 |
| 4 | Pizzzzzzzzzza Hutter | 5 |
| 5 | Pizzzzzzzzzza Hutter | 5 |

`southern_region` table

| id | name | franchise_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Burgers & Kings | 3 |
| 2 | Dominos | 4 |
| 3 | Pizzzzzzzzzza Hutter | 5 |

`franchise_locations`

| id | location | opening_date | franchise_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Earth | 2019-10-21 | 1 |
| 2 | Venus | 2020-10-21 | 1 |
| 3 | Mercury | 2020-07-04 | 2 |
| 4 | Saturn | 2020-09-14 | 3 |
| 5 | Mars | 2020-12-23 | 4 |
| 6 | Jupitor | 2020-02-16 | 4 |
| 7 | Pluto | 2020-04-14 | 5 |

I have the following requirements:

1. Only return unique stores (no duplicates)
2. return a concatenated list of opening_date

Here is my SQL with the current output:

( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6ad91/12 )

```
select s.id as store_id
  , s.name as store_name
  , case
      when f.id is not null then f.id
      when nr_f.id is not null then nr_f.id
      when sr_f.id is not null then sr_f.id
    end as franchise_id
  , case
      when f.id is not null then f.name
      when nr_f.id is not null then nr_f.name
      when sr_f.id is not null then sr_f.name
    end as franchise_name
  , fl.opening_date
from stores s
  left join franchise f on lower(s.name) = lower(f.name)
  left join northern_region nr on lower(s.name) = lower(nr.name)
  left join franchise nr_f on nr.franchise_id = nr_f.id
  left join southern_region sr on lower(s.name) = lower(sr.name)
  left join franchise sr_f on sr.franchise_id = sr_f.id
  left join franchise_locations fl 
    on f.id = fl.franchise_id
    or nr_f.id = fl.franchise_id
    or sr.id = fl.franchise_id
order by s.id
```

| store_id | store_name | franchise_id | franchise_name | opening_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mc Donalds | 1 | Mc Donalds | 2020-10-21 |
| 1 | Mc Donalds | 1 | Mc Donalds | 2019-10-21 |
| 2 | KFC | 2 | Kentucky | 2020-07-04 |
| 3 | Burgers & Kings | 3 | Burger King | 2019-10-21 |
| 3 | Burgers & Kings | 3 | Burger King | 2020-10-21 |
| 3 | Burgers & Kings | 3 | Burger King | 2020-09-14 |
| 4 | Dominos | 4 | Dominos Pizza | 2020-07-04 |
| 5 | Pizzzzzzzzzza Hutter | 5 | Pizza Hut | 2020-09-14 |
| 5 | Pizzzzzzzzzza Hutter | 5 | Pizza Hut | 2020-04-14 |
| 5 | Pizzzzzzzzzza Hutter | 5 | Pizza Hut | 2020-09-14 |
| 5 | Pizzzzzzzzzza Hutter | 5 | Pizza Hut | 2020-04-14 |
| 5 | Pizzzzzzzzzza Hutter | 5 | Pizza Hut | 2020-09-14 |
| 5 | Pizzzzzzzzzza Hutter | 5 | Pizza Hut | 2020-04-14 |

**Here is how I want the output to look:**

| store_id | store_name | franchise_id | franchise_name | opening_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mc Donalds | 1 | Mc Donalds | 2020-10-21,2019-10-21 |
| 2 | KFC | 2 | Kentucky | 2020-07-04 |
| 3 | Burgers & Kings | 3 | Burger King | 2019-10-21,2020-09-14 |
| 4 | Dominos | 4 | Dominos Pizza | 2020-07-04 |
| 5 | Pizzzzzzzzzza Hutter | 5 | Pizza Hut | 2020-09-14,2020-04-14 |

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your dates to strings you can concatenate them with the stuff() function and a group by.

See the link below for help on the stuff function and group by. You can also use a CTE to avoid writing out your query twice

[How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

couldn't test it without your tables, but this should get you most of the way

```
with YourQuery as (select s.id as store_id
   , s.name as store_name
   , case
     when f.id is not null then f.id
  when nr_f.id is not null then nr_f.id
  when sr_f.id is not null then sr_f.id
end as franchise_id
  , case
  when f.id is not null then f.name
  when nr_f.id is not null then nr_f.name
  when sr_f.id is not null then sr_f.name
end as franchise_name
, fl.opening_date
from stores s
left join franchise f on lower(s.name) = lower(f.name)
left join northern_region nr on lower(s.name) = lower(nr.name)
left join franchise nr_f on nr.franchise_id = nr_f.id
left join southern_region sr on lower(s.name) = lower(sr.name)
left join franchise sr_f on sr.franchise_id = sr_f.id
left join franchise_locations fl on f.id = fl.franchise_id
                                 or nr_f.id = fl.franchise_id
                                 or sr.id = fl.franchise_id
)


select store_id
     , store_name
     , franchise_id
     , franchise_name
     , STUFF((select ', ' + cast(y2.opening_date as varchar)
              from YourQuery y2
              where y1.store_id = y2.store_id
                and y1.store_name = y2.store_name
                and y1.franchise_id = y2.franchise_id
                and y1.franchise_name = y2.franchise_name
              for XML Path(''), Type)
       , 1,2,'')as Opening_Dates
from YourQuery y1
group by store_id, store_name, franchise_id, franchise_name
```

Comment: Thanks, the WITH clause helped me flatten the table! But I couldn't get the STUFF function to work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6ad91/35

Comment: ah, I didn't notice you were using postgresql, the for XML is a MSSQL function. My apologies.

Comment: to make it even harder, i'm actually using redshift but the sqlfiddles don't support redshift *sigh*